# Average delta value of a sequence of $N$ $8$-digit numbers

Tags: calculus, average

Given a sequence of $N$ $8$-digit numbers, how to calculate the average delta value, thanks.

Comment: @skullpatrol yes

Answer (score 1):

Divide the difference between the last element of the sequence and the first by $N-1$.

Comment: Definitely by $N-1$.  Edited to correct.

Comment: This assumes that the least of the numbers comes first and the greatest comes last, yes?

Comment: @Cameron, no, I was not assuming any particular order.

Comment: @DanBrumleve How does it work?